# Replace [a-z],[a-z] with [a-z], [a-z] and keep the letters

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How can I replace *[a-z],[a-z]* with *[a-z], [a-z]* and keeping the letters?

**Input**

```
suny stony brook, stony brook,usa.
```

**Output**

```
suny stony brook, stony brook, usa.
```

**What I have tried**

```
sed 's/[a-z],[a-z]/[a-z], [a-z]/g' <<< "suny stony brook, stony brook,usa."
sed 's/[a-z],[a-z]/, /g' <<< "suny stony brook, stony brook,usa."
```

Comment: you want to do this is bash shell only or you can use something else also?

Comment: any command line of bash shell

Comment: You can probably do it with two commands instead, first adding one space after every comma and then replace the comma + 2 spaces to delete the extra space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **What I have tried**
>
> ```
> sed 's/[a-z],[a-z]/[a-z], [a-z]/g' <<< "suny stony brook, stony brook,usa."
> ```

You need to use regex's *capture groups* here to refer to the original *[a-z]* values.

**For example:**

```
s/\([a-z]\),\([a-z]\)/\1, \2/g
```

Notice how I've surrounded those `[a-z]` with `\(` and `\)`?  These form *capture groups* that can be later referenced by writing `\1`, `\2`, etc.  (The number indicates their position.)

Alternatively, you could enable extended regexes by specifying the `-r` switch in `sed` (e.g. `sed -r`), in which case you only need to write `(` and `)` to form capture groups.

#### Putting it together

```
sed -re 's/([a-z]),([a-z])/\1, \2/g' <<<"suny stony brook, stony brook,usa."
```

Comment: and just please be aware that `[a-z]` can contain the characters `A`, `B`, etc. in some locales. If you want to portably and reliably only find lower case letter then use `[[:lower:]]`, not `[a-z]`.

Comment: Alternatively..  For portability, I'd specify `export LC_ALL=C` at the top of my bash script and be done with it.  (But I'm not one to guess what the OP expected exactly by *[a-z]*.)

Answer (score 3):

`-r` for Extended Regular Expression argument
`,[^ ]` for`,` without a ' ' after

```
sed -r 's/,([^ ])/, \1/g' <<< "suny stony brook, stony brook,usa."
```

get

```
suny stony brook, stony brook, usa.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a catch in the `sed` based approaches:

If there is a single (lowercase) character between 2 commas, it will only replace one (first) of them with `,<space>`.

e.g.

```
$ sed -re 's/([a-z]),([a-z])/\1, \2/g' <<<"suny stony brook, stony brook,u,sa."
suny stony brook, stony brook, u,sa.
```

If you know that your input would not contain that corner case, you are good to go with `sed` solution.

Else (if input can possibly contain such data), you have to use look-ahead / look-behind.
These are not available in `sed`. You have to use `perl` for that.

```
$ perl -ne 's/(?<=[a-z]),(?=[a-z])/, /g; print;' <<< "suny stony brook, stony brook,usa."
suny stony brook, stony brook, usa.

$ perl -ne 's/(?<=[a-z]),(?=[a-z])/, /g; print;' <<< "suny stony brook, stony brook,u,sa."
suny stony brook, stony brook, u, sa.
```

Note: The locale related warnings mentioned in other answers/comments would still apply. But their solutions are also provided in those comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `Gawk`, make use of `gensub`

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/([[:lower:]]),([[:lower:]])/,"\\1, \\2","g")}' <<<"suny stony brook, stony brook,usa."
suny stony brook, stony brook, usa.
```